# Is there a good replacement for !! (bang bang) in fish?

Tags: fish

I have recently been trying out fish shell, but one thing I keep running into is fish's lack of the `!!` command/builtin.

I cannot seem to find a good alternative or replacement for fish. Does one exist?

Comment: Hi Seth - there is a discussion and potential work around here - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fish#History_Substitution

Comment: question also asked here http://superuser.com/q/719531/4714

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From git-hub - https://gist.github.com/crossroads1112/77badb2c3455e23b873b

```
# Add this to your ~/.config/fish/config.fish
# Syntax:
# To just rerun your last command, simply type '!!'
# '!! sudo' will prepend sudo to your most recent command
# Running !! with anything other than sudo will append the argument to your most recent command
# To add another command to prepend list remove the # on line 10 and put the command in the quotes. Repeat as needed
function !!;
  set var (history | head -n 1)
  if test $argv
    if test $argv = "sudo"        #; or "any other command you want to prepend"
        eval $argv $var
    else
        eval $var $argv
    end
    else
        eval $var
  end
end
```

Comment: Aha! I *almost* wrote that exact function on my own, but mine had a few critical differences. Awesome!